# Trying to run script on boot, but "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, raspberry-pi

I've been struggling with this issue for a while, when I run `python3 main.py` my code runs, however when I try `sudo python3 main.py` it can't find the module that I've downloaded.
This hasn't been an issue until now, I want to run on boot, I have tried to edit the rc.local file, which needs superuser permission but of course it does not run without permission. 
Also, when I install modules using the terminal, it doesn't seem to work at all, until I open thonny and download the modules that way, I can't see what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: its because your pip is installing modules to your `/home/<username>/.local/` folder and sudo runs the command as root so root user has no access to that folder. To fix that, you can install a package system wide for all users by doing `sudo -H pip install <package>`